# Everscale Solidity error by timeout: code: 3025 Contract execution was terminated with error

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, everscale

Free TON Solidity code or execution error. Can't understand my mistake, I already compact the code to the minimum:

cat ./SimpleStorage.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

tonos-cli call 0:efbeed7533cae6f12869b665b610c30535397c5c1523f6b41561905807aed958 set '{"x":100}' --abi ./SimpleStorage.abi.json

> ```
> Input arguments:
> address: 0:efbeed7533cae6f12869b665b610c30535397c5c1523f6b41561905807aed958
> method: set
> params: {"x":100}
> abi: ./SimpleStorage.abi.json
> ```

Then in result I get an error by timeout:

> ```
> code: 3025
> message: Contract execution was terminated with error
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable gas before You store variables. [tvm.accept](https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-Solidity-Compiler/blob/master/API.md#tvmaccept) can do it.

```
  function set(uint x) public {
        tvm.accept();
        storedData = x;
  }
```